# For Loop only looked for first element of a list while using if condition within the loop. (Python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, loops, for-loop

```
def has23(nums):
    for i in nums:
        if i == 2 or i == 3:
            return True
        else:
            return False


print has23([4,3])
```

The function has to return True if list in the parameter has either 2 or 3 in it. The output resulted 'False' even though the list has 3 in it.

Why?

Comment: Because your function returns after checking the first element.

Answer (score 0):

`return` ends the function and returns back to the place where the function was called. That you happened to be in a for loop inside the function isn't relevant anymore.

A function can only return once.